# Importing function from module inside class doesn't find self

Tags: python, class, import

Suppose I have the following file structure:

```
default
├── __init__.py
└── utils
    ├── helper.py
    └── __init__.py
```

I want to create a class and since I don't want it to be a very large file, I divide the functions into multiple files. My utils functions are stored in the `utils` directory.

Inside the first `__init__.py` I define a class that calls the module `utils`:

```
class Default():

    def __init__(self):

        self.test = 1

    from . import utils
```

And inside `utils` I have some functions in `helper.py`:

```
def my_func(self, x):
    return self.test+x
```

I thought that `my_func` would be a method in `Default` and could then "see" the self, but that is not what happens:

```
>>> from default import Default
>>> d = Default()
>>> d.utils.helper.my_func(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: my_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

So, I want to know if it is possible to do something like this, or the `my_func` has to be inside the class definition.

Comment: Only functions that are attributes of the class will be used as methods. In your example, none of the functions are, rather, the module is an attribute of the class. Honestly, this approach seems really confusing from the perspective of reading your code. But if you *are* going to do this, you should at least be explicit, in the class, `my_func = utils.my_func` etc etc

Comment: More broadly, though, this isn't really a solution to the problem of your class being to big, which should be fixed by refactoring your design, not by squirreling away functions in separate modules. Now you have the problem of a class that is too big, with the source code spread out all over the place making it even *more* opaque